# Condition for a Trigger in Workflow Foundation

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4.5

I have to implement a workflow in our application and decided to give Windows Workflow Foundation a try. Using the documentation and tutorials from MS I designed a basic Workflow with custom Activities. I have a custom activity as a Trigger for a Transition from State A to State B. This activity creates a Bookmark which is executed / resumed by the user after a while. This works as expected.

But now I'm stuck.  I'd like to define a condition for the Trigger of this transition which only allows the user to resume the Bookmark if the condition is met (e.g. the user must have special rights or a property must be set).

What I see in the Workflow Foundation Editor is, that I can define a condition for the Transition, that is evaluated after the Bookmark is resumed but I need this before.

Has anybody done sth. like this or a hint how to solve this Issue?

Comment: Can you add what code you have thus far? What have you tried? What were your expectations? How did the system operate contrary to your expectation?

Comment: @c45207: There are only a few lines of code to implement the custom acitivty. Also the system doesn't operate contrary to my expactation. I want to add a condition before the Trigger (resuming the bookmark of my custom activity) for my Transition. Basically the user should only be able to resume the bookmark if a condition is met but I can't find something to do this.

Answer (score 0):

ResumeBookmark does take a input with type object. This will be available in your BookmarkCallback. Once bookmark resumed you may evaluate the input and make decision based on the input value. If the evaluation is passed, move to your next state, otherwise go back to itself.

You want the control to happen before resume bookmark, but my alternative is to allow the bookmark resume, then evaluate the access control. Will that work for you?